# I want to extract only last two numeric values from a string variable in SAS

Tags: string, numbers, sas

I want to extract only last two numeric values from a string variable and assign it to a new variable. Firstly i have extracted all the numeric values from the string using the code below and assigned it to a new variable but i ultimately want to extract only the last two numeric values so is there any better way to do this.

```
UI_DUM = input(compress(Prod_Desc,,"kd"),best.);
```

And one more question is: how to assign a temp variable for doing some manupulation work in SAS?

Comment: Could you share an example?

Comment: If it's a string look at substr function. You should post what your original data looks like and what you expect your output to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code.
You are doing it right, to remove the characters and keeping only digits. The same is being done for variable "temp1"(in the below code).
In the second step, using the `length` function, to calculate the total length of the string which now contains only digits. In the third step using the `substr` function to extract the last two digits.
If you want to do it in one statement, "final" variable is the answer.

---

- [LENGTH](http://support.sas.com/kb/35/848.html) Function - Returns the length of a non-blank character string, excluding
  trailing blanks, and returns 1 for a blank character string
- [compress](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212246.htm) function with "[kd](http://support.sas.com/kb/33/352.html)" option - would keep only digits.

  COMPRESS(<, chars><, modifiers>)

  Modifier - specifies a character constant, variable, or expression in which each non-blank character modifies the action of the COMPRESS function. Blanks are ignored. The following characters can be used as modifiers.

  d or D adds digits to the list of characters.

  k or K keeps the characters in the list instead of removing them
- [substr](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212264.htm) function - Extracts a substring from an argument - 
  SUBSTR(string, position<,length>)

---

```
data _null_;
Test_string="ada13117a1w11da1286s";
temp1=compress(Test_string, , 'kd');
temp2=length(temp1);
temp3=substr(temp1,temp2-1,2);
final=substr(compress(Test_string, , 'kd'),length(compress(temp1))-1,2);
put _all_;
run;
```

Regarding the temp variable, there is no such one in SAS. Just use any variable name and use the drop statement in final dataset  like below;

```
data test(drop = temp); /*Would work as the temp variable*/
temp= 2*balance;/*just for example*/
/*use the temp in further calculations*/
run;
```

Comment: Actually, there are a few temporary variables.  `_N_`, `_ERROR_`, and the FIRST/LAST variables are all temporary variables, plus temporary arrays.  Some poeple like to use `_N_` for a temporary variable, though I find it a bit messy unless I'm doing my own data step (a DOW loop or similar).

Comment: Yes, you are right, but as I understand the OP's requirement, he is looking to hold some calculated number in it, am not sure if these automatic variables could be used for that.

Comment: I don't disagree with your result, just commenting on the exactness of the statement :)

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat different take:

```
data want;
  set have;
  UI_DUM = input(compress(Prod_Desc,,"kd"),best.);
  UI_DUM_last2 = mod(UI_DUM,100);
run;
```

You could do that all in one line of course as well.  This uses the numeric modulo function to simply give you the last 2 digits (any number modulo 100 will return the final 2 digits).

Comment: ..clever :) but wouldn't it be a bit slower than my answer, as you are doing mathematical operation here.